# MapKit JS - Center Map Around Coordinates

Tags: javascript

I'm creating a custom map using Apple MapKit JS using the [Custom Callout example](https://developer.apple.com/maps/web/) from the Apple website. I've included the full code for the example from the Apple website below.

I would now like to specify the center co-ordinates and have the map centered around those. I've had a look at the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkitjs/map/2973914-center) and tried adding:

```
var center = new mapkit.Coordinate(37.8184493, -122.478409);
```

so this section now looks as follows:

```
var map = new mapkit.Map("map");
var center = new mapkit.Coordinate(37.8184493, -122.478409);
map.showItems(annotations);
```

but that isn't changing how the map displays and doesn't center around the specified co-ordinates. I'm not sure at this point if I have the wrong syntax here or what the correct way to center the map here is.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
        
        <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        
        <script src="https://cdn.apple-mapkit.com/mk/5.x.x/mapkit.js"></script>
        
        <style>
        #map {
            height: 600px;
        }
        
        a:link, a:visited {
            color: #2aaef5;
            outline: none;
            text-decoration: none;
        }
        
        .landmark {
            width: 250px;
            padding: 7px 0 0 0;
            background: rgba(247, 247, 247, 0.75);
            border-radius: 5px;
            box-shadow: 10px 10px 50px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.29);
            font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
            -webkit-transform-origin: 0 10px;
            transform-origin: 0 10px;
        }
        
        .landmark h1 {
            margin-top: 0;
            padding: 5px 15px;
            background: #2aaef5;
            color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);
            font-size: 16px;
            font-weight: 300;
        }
        
        .landmark section {
            padding: 0 15px 5px;
            font-size: 14px;
        }
        
        .landmark section p {
            margin: 5px 0;
        }
        
        .landmark:after {
            content: "";
            position: absolute;
            top: 7px;
            left: -13px;
            width: 0;
            height: 0;
            margin-bottom: -13px;
            border-right: 13px solid #2aaef5;
            border-top: 13px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
            border-bottom: 13px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
        }
        
        @-webkit-keyframes scale-and-fadein {
            0% {
                -webkit-transform: scale(0.2);
                opacity: 0;
            }
        
            100% {
                -webkit-transform: scale(1);
                opacity: 1;
            }
        }
        
        @keyframes scale-and-fadein {
            0% {
                transform: scale(0.2);
                opacity: 0;
            }
        
            100% {
                transform: scale(1);
                opacity: 1;
            }
        }
        </style>
        
        </head>
        
        <body>
        <div id="map"></div>
        
        <script>
        mapkit.init({
            authorizationCallback: function(done) {
                var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
                xhr.open("GET", "/services/jwt");
                xhr.addEventListener("load", function() {
                    done(this.responseText);
                });
                xhr.send();
            }
        });
        
        // Landmarks data
        var sanFranciscoLandmarks = [
            { coordinate: new mapkit.Coordinate(37.7951315, -122.402986), title: "Transamerica Pyramid", phone: "+1-415-983-5420", url: "http://www.transamericapyramidcenter.com/" },
            { coordinate: new mapkit.Coordinate(37.7954201, -122.39352), title: "Ferry Building", phone: "+1 (415) 983-8030", url: "http://www.ferrybuildingmarketplace.com" },
            { coordinate: new mapkit.Coordinate(37.8083396, -122.415727), title: "Fisherman's Wharf", phone: "+1 (415) 673-3530", url: "http://visitfishermanswharf.com" },
            { coordinate: new mapkit.Coordinate(37.8023553, -122.405742), title: "Coit Tower", phone: "+1 (415) 249-0995", url: "http://sfrecpark.org/destination/telegraph-hill-pioneer-park/coit-tower/" },
            { coordinate: new mapkit.Coordinate(37.7552305, -122.452624), title: "Sutro Tower", phone: "+1 (415) 681-8850", url: "http://www.sutrotower.com" },
            { coordinate: new mapkit.Coordinate(37.779267, -122.419269), title: "City Hall", phone: "+1 (415) 701-2311", url: "http://sfgsa.org/index.aspx?page=1085" },
            { coordinate: new mapkit.Coordinate(37.8184493, -122.478409), title: "Golden Gate Bridge", phone: "+1 (415) 921-5858", url: "http://www.goldengatebridge.org" },
            { coordinate: new mapkit.Coordinate(37.7785538, -122.514035), title: "Cliff House", phone: "+1 (415) 386-3330", url: "http://www.cliffhouse.com/" }
        ];
        
        // Landmark annotation callout delegate
        var CALLOUT_OFFSET = new DOMPoint(-148, -78);
        var landmarkAnnotationCallout = {
            calloutElementForAnnotation: function(annotation) {
                return calloutForLandmarkAnnotation(annotation);
            },
        
            calloutAnchorOffsetForAnnotation: function(annotation, element) {
                return CALLOUT_OFFSET;
            },
        
            calloutAppearanceAnimationForAnnotation: function(annotation) {
                return ".4s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0, 1.5) 0s 1 normal scale-and-fadein";
            }
        };
        
        // Landmarks annotations
        var annotations = sanFranciscoLandmarks.map(function(landmark) {
            var annotation = new mapkit.MarkerAnnotation(landmark.coordinate, {
                callout: landmarkAnnotationCallout,
                color: "#c969e0"
            });
            annotation.landmark = landmark;
            return annotation;
        });
        
        var map = new mapkit.Map("map");
        map.showItems(annotations);
        
        // Landmark annotation custom callout
        function calloutForLandmarkAnnotation(annotation) {
            var div = document.createElement("div");
            div.className = "landmark";
        
            var title = div.appendChild(document.createElement("h1"));
            title.textContent = annotation.landmark.title;
        
            var section = div.appendChild(document.createElement("section"));
        
            var phone = section.appendChild(document.createElement("p"));
            phone.className = "phone";
            phone.textContent = annotation.landmark.phone;
        
            var link = section.appendChild(document.createElement("p"));
            link.className = "homepage";
            var a = link.appendChild(document.createElement("a"));
            a.href = annotation.landmark.url;
            a.textContent = "website";
        
            return div;
        }
        </script>
        </body>
        </html>
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't get what you meant by "specify the center co-ordinates and have the map centered around those", when I run your snippet, all the coordinates you provided are in the center of the screen. Could you elaborate more on your intention?

Comment: It appears that MapKit JS shows all the annotations and centres the map around the middle of these. I would like to specify one of those to be used as the centre and have MapKit JS position that at the centre of the map. I'm not concerned with having all annotations appear on the map when fist viewed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the documentation, you should use [setCenterAnimated](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkitjs/map/2973935-setcenteranimated), so in this case you can use the following lines:

```
...
var map = new mapkit.Map("map");
map.showItems(annotations);

// add the following lines
var center = new mapkit.Coordinate(37.8184493, -122.478409);
map.setCenterAnimated(center)
...
```

And this is the modified snippet:

```js
mapkit.init({
  authorizationCallback: function(done) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("GET", "/services/jwt");
    xhr.addEventListener("load", function() {
      done(this.responseText);
    });
    xhr.send();
  }
});



// Landmarks data
var sanFranciscoLandmarks = [{
    coordinate: new mapkit.Coordinate(37.7951315, -122.402986),
    title: "Transamerica Pyramid",
    phone: "+1-415-983-5420",
    url: "http://www.transamericapyramidcenter.com/"
  },
  {
    coordinate: new mapkit.Coordinate(37.7954201, -122.39352),
    title: "Ferry Building",
    phone: "+1 (415) 983-8030",
    url: "http://www.ferrybuildingmarketplace.com"
  },
  {
    coordinate: new mapkit.Coordinate(37.8083396, -122.415727),
    title: "Fisherman's Wharf",
    phone: "+1 (415) 673-3530",
    url: "http://visitfishermanswharf.com"
  },
  {
    coordinate: new mapkit.Coordinate(37.8023553, -122.405742),
    title: "Coit Tower",
    phone: "+1 (415) 249-0995",
    url: "http://sfrecpark.org/destination/telegraph-hill-pioneer-park/coit-tower/"
  },
  {
    coordinate: new mapkit.Coordinate(37.7552305, -122.452624),
    title: "Sutro Tower",
    phone: "+1 (415) 681-8850",
    url: "http://www.sutrotower.com"
  },
  {
    coordinate: new mapkit.Coordinate(37.779267, -122.419269),
    title: "City Hall",
    phone: "+1 (415) 701-2311",
    url: "http://sfgsa.org/index.aspx?page=1085"
  },
  {
    coordinate: new mapkit.Coordinate(37.8184493, -122.478409),
    title: "Golden Gate Bridge",
    phone: "+1 (415) 921-5858",
    url: "http://www.goldengatebridge.org"
  },
  {
    coordinate: new mapkit.Coordinate(37.7785538, -122.514035),
    title: "Cliff House",
    phone: "+1 (415) 386-3330",
    url: "http://www.cliffhouse.com/"
  }
];

// Landmark annotation callout delegate
var CALLOUT_OFFSET = new DOMPoint(-148, -78);
var landmarkAnnotationCallout = {
  calloutElementForAnnotation: function(annotation) {
    return calloutForLandmarkAnnotation(annotation);
  },

  calloutAnchorOffsetForAnnotation: function(annotation, element) {
    return CALLOUT_OFFSET;
  },

  calloutAppearanceAnimationForAnnotation: function(annotation) {
    return ".4s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0, 1.5) 0s 1 normal scale-and-fadein";
  }
};

// Landmarks annotations
var annotations = sanFranciscoLandmarks.map(function(landmark) {
  var annotation = new mapkit.MarkerAnnotation(landmark.coordinate, {
    callout: landmarkAnnotationCallout,
    color: "#c969e0"
  });
  annotation.landmark = landmark;
  return annotation;
});

var map = new mapkit.Map("map");
map.showItems(annotations);

var center = new mapkit.Coordinate(37.8184493, -122.478409);
map.setCenterAnimated(center)

// Landmark annotation custom callout
function calloutForLandmarkAnnotation(annotation) {
  var div = document.createElement("div");
  div.className = "landmark";

  var title = div.appendChild(document.createElement("h1"));
  title.textContent = annotation.landmark.title;

  var section = div.appendChild(document.createElement("section"));

  var phone = section.appendChild(document.createElement("p"));
  phone.className = "phone";
  phone.textContent = annotation.landmark.phone;

  var link = section.appendChild(document.createElement("p"));
  link.className = "homepage";
  var a = link.appendChild(document.createElement("a"));
  a.href = annotation.landmark.url;
  a.textContent = "website";

  return div;
}
```

```css
#map {
  height: 600px;
}

a:link,
a:visited {
  color: #2aaef5;
  outline: none;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.landmark {
  width: 250px;
  padding: 7px 0 0 0;
  background: rgba(247, 247, 247, 0.75);
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 10px 10px 50px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.29);
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 0 10px;
  transform-origin: 0 10px;
}

.landmark h1 {
  margin-top: 0;
  padding: 5px 15px;
  background: #2aaef5;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 300;
}

.landmark section {
  padding: 0 15px 5px;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.landmark section p {
  margin: 5px 0;
}

.landmark:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 7px;
  left: -13px;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  margin-bottom: -13px;
  border-right: 13px solid #2aaef5;
  border-top: 13px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  border-bottom: 13px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}

@-webkit-keyframes scale-and-fadein {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.2);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@keyframes scale-and-fadein {
  0% {
    transform: scale(0.2);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.apple-mapkit.com/mk/5.x.x/mapkit.js"></script>

<div id="map"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks @damzaky that's great. Do you know how to also control the zoom level in the above example so I can have it zoom in/out to a specified setting when first loaded?

Comment: @user982124 hmm i'm not sure yet, maybe make another SO question so that others can help too?

Comment: the thing is, apple's documentation is always so hard to navigate, and i'm not an expert in it

Comment: `setCameraDistanceAnimated(40000)` will zoom the map to 40,000 meters